# g++ undefined reference to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, linker, g++, undefined-reference

I'm compiling and linking a cpp file against a pre-compiled library, and I'm getting an "undefined reference" error.

Firstly, this is the command (the library in question is quicknet3, the program I'm compiling is trapper):

`g++ -w -g -I. -g -O3 -pipe -Wall -I/home/install/x86_64/include/quicknet3  -L/home/install/x86_64/lib -lquicknet3 -lintvec -lfltvec -o trapper trapper.cpp CMyException.cpp`

Here's the undefined reference error:

`/tmp/ccFuVczF.o: In function 'main':
trapper.cpp:1731: undefined reference to 'QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile::QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile(int, char const*, _IO_FILE*, int)'`

The call in trapper.cpp (line 1731) is:

`IN_PFILE = new QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile(0, "", fp, 1);`

where `fp` is a `FILE *`, assigned as the result of an `fopen` call beforehand.

The constructor being called is defined in the relevant header file (QN_Pfile.h), as follows:

`class QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile : public
QN_InFtrLabStream

{

public:

    QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile(int a_debug, const char* a_dbgname, FILE* a_file, int a_indexed);

(... other declarations ...)
}`

The definition of the constructor is indeed given in QN_Pfile.cc:

`QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile::QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile(int a_debug,const char* a_dbgname,    FILE* a_file, int a_indexed) : log(a_debug, "QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile", a_dbgname),file(a_file),indexed(a_indexed),buffer(NULL),sentind(NULL)
{

(... the usual constructor stuff :P ...)
}`

I compiled the quicknet3 library myself, without error, and installed it to /home/install/x86_64/lib/libquicknet3.a

So, I can't understand why the call from trapper.cpp is unable to find the reference to this constructor definition. The g++ arguments of `-L/home/install/x86_64/lib -lquicknet3` should do the trick, right?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround is to add /home/install/x86_64/lib/libquicknet3.a to g++ commandline.

I you want to investigate further, if g++ is picking another copy of libquicknet3, you can pass -v to g++ so it will output its searching paths.

Comment: This works. But why?? Shouldn't "-L/home/n4739094/install/x86_64/lib -lquicknet3" have exactly the same effect as /home/n4739094/install/x86_64/lib/libquicknet3.a? I tried using -v but couldn't make any sense of its "searching paths" - any hints? Thanks :)

Comment: Using -lquicknet is telling the linker that search libquicknet3.a in the libraries path, which includes your home directory, my guess is that the linker is using a copy in another path, unfortunately the gcc docs at hand don't tell me which is the search order.

Comment: With the -v option you have to take a look at LIBRARY_PATH and collect2 invocation. `g++ ... 2>&1 | egrep 'collect2|LIBRARY_PATH'`

Comment: Hi Ismael, following is the collect2 line in the output of the make command - as you can see, LIBRARY_PATH is not mentioned. Also, of all the paths specified with -L, libquicknet3.a is only found in /home/n4739094/install/x86_64/lib.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o trapper /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/crtbegin.o -L/home/n4739094/install/x86_64/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64

Comment: -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../.. -lquicknet3 -lintvec -lfltvec /tmp/ccU6Az7j.o /tmp/ccBAv9uQ.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o`

Answer (score 3):

I notice that you're mixing `FILE*` and `_IO_FILE*`.  I'm not familiar with the latter, are you sure they're one and the same?

Comment: Not really, but if this were the problem, wouldn't the error message be more like "no matching function for call..."? Anyway, Aaron's suggestion didn't work (casting to FILE*)

Answer (score 1):

FILE is a typedef of `_IO_FILE`. Your linker is treating it as a unique type.

You could try:

```
IN_PFILE = new QN_InFtrLabStream_PFile(0, "", (FILE *)fp, 1);
```

to see if this resolve your constructor.

(FILE is defined in stdio.h, _IO_FILE in libio.h if you're interested)